# How to do a LIKE considering two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, sql-like

I have a customer table with two columns `first_name` and `last_name`.

How can I use LIKE in a query being able to get data from both columns at same time?

For instance:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'full_name' 
FROM customer WHERE full_name LIKE 'John D%'
```

I've tried this and it tells me `full_name` column doesn't exist.

Comment: [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) is the most efficient means in SQL to do what you want.

Comment: @OMG As I could change the table and the data insertion, I created a new indexed column full_name and used it instead due to performance issues mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'full_name' 
FROM customer WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE 'John D%'
```

Comment: You might also want to trim the first_name and last_name to account for possible extra spaces in the columns.

Comment: You also might check a "lastname, firstname" variant if the user can input that as well.

Comment: So Simple, brilliant. danke :)

Comment: 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What is wrong with using 'full_name' in where clause?

Answer (score 6):

You are almost there

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer 
WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE 'John D%'
```

Note: this may not have very good performance. You might want to consider [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 4):

Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'full_name' 
   FROM customer HAVING full_name LIKE 'John D%'
```

Comment: Why HAVING instead of WHERE?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MySql at hand, but can't u do something like the code below?

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'full_name' 
FROM customer WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE 'John D%'
```

Disclaimer: THIS COULD BE VERY SLOW!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer 
WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE 'John D%'
```

might be very slow but that won't matter if your database is quite small.  When using `CONCAT` make sure the Collation is same for both the column names or else it will fetch you an error.

Below is a statement for when I want my `LIKE` statement to work for both category name and course name.  I check for cat_id in both tables so that I can have an idea which course belongs to which category.

```
SELECT * FROM courses a INNER JOIN categories b ON a.cat_id=b.cat_id 
WHERE CONCAT(b.cat_name,' ',a.course_name)
LIKE :name ORDER BY b.cat_id
```

:name is placeholder (PDO)